# Google Maps & Geocode

Tags: javascript, maps, geocode

I started playing around with Google Maps API yesterday, very interesting..

Having a slight issue though.. I'm attempting to make a search function which uses geocode. For some reason it doesn't move the map to the retrieved search results area. I know it retrieves the coordinates fine, I added a `alert();` which displayed them fine..

LIVE DEMO: http://teknologix.net/test.html

I suspect it has something to do with the map variable being defined with in the `initialize()` function. I'm not 100% sure though:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB4iGeXYKfqv65-8c9UbR1qPavZb6VFXCU&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var map;

function geocodePosition(pos) {
  geocoder.geocode({
    latLng: pos
  }, function(responses) {
    if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
      updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);
    } else {
      updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');
    }
  });
}

function updateMarkerStatus(str) {
  document.getElementById('markerStatus').innerHTML = str;
}

function updateMarkerPosition(latLng) {
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = [
    latLng.lat(),
    latLng.lng()
  ].join(', ');
}

function updateMarkerAddress(str) {
  document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = str;
}

function initialize() {
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.90616588876475, 151.15102333450318);
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
    zoom: 15,
    center: latLng,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    zoomControl: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    title: 'Point A',
    map: map,
    draggable: true
  });

  // Update current position info.
  updateMarkerPosition(latLng);
  geocodePosition(latLng);

  // Add dragging event listeners.
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function() {
    updateMarkerAddress('Dragging...');
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {
    updateMarkerStatus('Dragging...');
    updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
    updateMarkerStatus('Drag ended');
    geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
    map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    marker.setPosition(map.getCenter());
    updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());
  });
}

function codeAddress() {
    var address2 = document.getElementById('target').value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address2}, function(results) {
            alert(results[0].geometry.location);
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <style>
   html { height: 100% }
   body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
  #mapCanvas {
    height: 85%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
  }
  #infoPanel div {
    background: white;
    top: 0px;
    position: relative;
    height: 20px;
    width: 500px;
  }
  </style>

  <div id="mapCanvas"></div>
  <div id="infoPanel">
    <b>Marker status:</b>
    <div id="markerStatus"><i>Click and drag the marker.</i></div>
    <b>Current position:</b>
    <div id="info"></div>
    <b>Closest matching address:</b>
    <div id="address"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
      <input id="target" type="textbox" value="Sydney, NSW">
      <input type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="codeAddress();">
      <input type="button" value="Test" onclick="test();">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help will be appreciated! Thank you for reading!

Comment: The link you posted (http://teknologix.net/test.html) is not valid (shows 404 page).

Answer (score 0):

A first thing to try would be to change the `initialize()` function so you don't redeclare the `map` variable within that function's scope. In other words, change `var map = ...` to `map = ...`, which will set the value of the global `map` variable.